# Using the null-coalescing operator: to return

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method  to that takes a 2 dimensional array and uses the null -coalescing operator to find nulls.It should then print how many null and how many non-null elements there are 
Here is the code

```
static void NullSearcherWithCoalecsingOperators(int?[,] TwoDArr)
   {
       int? NonNull = 0;
       int? Null = 0;

       for (int i=0;i<TwoDArr.GetLength(0);i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < TwoDArr.GetLength(1); j++)
           {
              TwoDArr[i,j] = NonNull++ ?? Null++;
            }
       }
       Console.WriteLine($"There are {NonNull} nonnull elements and {Null} null elements in this 2d array");
   }
```

Trouble is that it always prints that everything is not null and nothing is null.
I'm wondering why the ++ isn't working  on the right side?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use such a convoluted way to do this?

Comment: You're not even checking if the value in the array is null, just if `NonNull` is null.

Comment: Also note, the so called "find nulls" method is actually modifying the array content.

Comment: And incrementing a null `int?` will just result in null.

Comment: I think what you're after is more like `var _ = TwoDArr[i,j] == null ? Null++ : NonNull++;` but you'd have to change `Null` and `NonNull` to `int` instead of `int?`.

Comment: If you look for a good way to count null / not null array elements, you should probably modify your question. There are solutions to most problems, but good solutions will not satisfy your "use the coalesce operator" constraints. And I hope noone will give you a bad solution :)

Comment: Thanks juharr that worked.But I was specifically looking for a way to do this with the null coalescing operator.Since that was the assigment

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I won't just solve it all for you... a tip: count the nulls, then use math to calculate the not-nulls instead of trying to count not-null the same way as you count the nulls. You can increment a variable based on a null int, by assigning the value to some unused variable and coalescing to your counter `var unused = PotentiallyNullInteger ?? CountMyNullValues++;`

Answer (score 2):

It would be better you stick to conventional `if` condition here.

```
if(TwoDArr[i,j].HasValue)
    NonNull++;
else
    Null++;
```

However, if you do not want to use conventional `if` Condition, then you could use

```
var _ = TwoDArr[i,j].HasValue? NonNull++ : Null++;
```

or

```
(TwoDArr[i,j].HasValue? ref NonNull : ref Null) +=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are checking if the variable NonNull is null and, since it is assigned a value at declaration, it never is null..

In other words, this line

```
TwoDArr[i,j] = NonNull++ ?? Null++;
```

is checking if NonNull is null using the ?? operator.  Since it is not null it increments the value and assigns it back to the array (are you sure you want this assignment?).

I think you want to use the ?? operator against the array element.